# Error 18456 while connecting error while trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am completely new to databases.. I am doing a small application which needs to connect to a SQL Server database.

1. My SQL Server is installed on the company server
2. I am trying to login to SQL Server from my local system

Steps I have tried so far:

1. Since I have admin credentials to the company server I have logged in and included myself (SQL Server authentication) under security -> logins

So now when I try to connect from my local computer it is giving me "Login failed for user (Microsoft SQL Server error 18456)".

Can any one please help me with this?

Goal: I want to connect to companies server from my local machine.

Comment: Look into SQL-Server log for more details about the error http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx